# Objectify - how to create child entites with a parent Key that points to a nonexistant entity

Tags: objectify

Given that, in Objectify, an entity group is not defined by a class, but by an instance, and that you can create child entites with a parent Key that points to a nonexistant entity, how would you do that? (I'm looking for a simple example. The statements above are from Objectify documentation, and I'm confused.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Key with an arbitrary id.  A simple example:

```
class Foo {
    @Parent Key<Par> parent;
    @Id Long id;
    // ...constructors, etc
}

// Create a parent key for which an entity may or may not exist, doesn't matter
Key<Par> parent = Key.create(Par.class, 123L);

Foo foo = new Foo(parent, someId);
ofy().save().entity(foo).now();
```

Comment: fyi that method will end up not returning an entity for a fetch like this: 
myEntity = ofy().load().type(POJO.class).id('id').safeGet();
Where the POJO was persisted with @Parent key, for which an entity did not exist, i.e, in its constructor: this.parent = Key.create(POJO.class, anId);
The entity will persist, but won't be fetchable.

Comment: ofy().load().type(POJO.class).parent(parentKey).id(id).safeGet()

Comment: Alternatively, just construct the full key and fetch that:  ofy().load().key(thefullyformedkey).safeGet()